# On button end running methods in different method

Tags: c#, loops, managementeventwatcher

So I have some code which checks for the plugin and removal of a USB device.

```
public void Main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watcheradd = new ManagementEventWatcher();
            var queryadd = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
            watcheradd.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_deviceadded);
            watcheradd.Query = queryadd;
            watcheradd.Start();


            var watcherremove = new ManagementEventWatcher();
            var queryremove = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 3");
            watcherremove.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_deviceremoved);
            watcherremove.Query = queryremove;
            watcherremove.Start();   
}
```

I was wondering is there anyway I can stop the `watchremove` and `watcheradd` loops before my program exits to prevent an exception by the stop code within:

```
     private void Exit_Main(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        ProcessStartInfo si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        si.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        si.CreateNoWindow = true;
        si.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.FileName = "adb.exe";
        si.Arguments = "kill-server";
        p = Process.Start(si);
        p.WaitForExit();

        Application.Exit();
        //EXIT APPLICATION!!!            
    }
```

as `Main_Shown.deviceadd.Stop();` isn't the correct syntax or way of doing this.
The result should safely stop the above loops and then allow the program to exit without an exception.

Comment: Why is **Stop** not correct?
Do you mean to intercept closing application event?
Could you please clarify?

Comment: as its running within a different method it wouldn't work. I edited the original code to reflect this.

Comment: If you want to call the Stop() method then the watcheradd and watcherremove cannot be local variables.  Make them fields of the class.

Comment: Just to clear something up. Would I use `{}` to encase watcheradd and watcherremove and then I can call it elsewhere? Or would it require more from that. Link to article [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173118%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution.
So I needed to add

```
 ManagementEventWatcher watcheradd = new ManagementEventWatcher();
    WqlEventQuery queryadd = new WqlEventQuery();
    ManagementEventWatcher watcherremove = new ManagementEventWatcher();
    WqlEventQuery queryremove = new WqlEventQuery();
```

above the class and that set the classes to global. So now it exits without a problem using the code below.

```
`si.FileName = "adb.exe";
        si.Arguments = "kill-server";
        p = Process.Start(si);
        p.WaitForExit();
        watcherremove.Stop();
        watcheradd.Stop();
        Application.Exit();
        //EXIT APPLICATION!!`
```

Thanks everyone for your help.